# Which region of Google Cloud Services to use to reduce cost and latency

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am using google cloud platform to host my services. I have the following services running to support my application

1. App Engine
2. Cloud Sql
3. Cloud Storage

I need help in understanding which region to use to reduce latency and pricing. The application users will be based out of India. Based on the availibity of the above services, below is what I can do best

1. App Engine - asia-northeast1
2. Cloud Sql - asia-east1/asia-northeast1
3. Cloud Storage - asia-southeast1/asia-east1/asia-northeast1

The region "asia-southeast1" works best for me in terms of distance. But having all the three different regions is not adviced by google.

Is hosting all the three in asia-northeast1 the best option for me?

Comment: It depends on your use case, but in general it's best to co-locate your computing with your data if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise against storing your application in a different region/data center as your database as it will introduce a large latency for every single database operation.

And as each request of a complex application will most likely have more database operations than round trips to the user, it makes sense to put the App and DB in the same region even if it means putting them slightly further away from users.

As far as cloud storage is concerned, if you set your storage buckets to have Multi Region Availability (which they are set to have by default) then the initial region you placed them in makes no difference as Google will serve each user from the closest region to them

Comment: I am primarliy using storage to store the files. I am then using servingUrl to serve the file to my users. Do I still need to use Multi Region availbility for the buckets?

Comment: I think once you create a serving URL for a file, Google copies it and continues serving it from a different location (although this is completely abstracted from the user) 

So the properties of the bucket shouldn't make a difference if everything is accessed with serving URLs